# How to display the plist value into the tableview as checkmark?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I having an application in which I have tableview where there are 5 rows (entertainment, retail, health, Food, Services) in tableview. When I initially run my application I want that values (entertainment, retail, health) should from be fetched my plist and depending on the values I want to display the checkmark on my tableview.

In other words, when I click on tableview controller, by default first 3 rows should display checkmark on it by fetching values from the plist and when I change the value by clicking the row that particular value should get saved to my plist array.

Answer (score 1):

Just save a bool value in your plist with each entry.  So I would make each entry a dictionary with two values. One is the title and the other is a bool value.

Or alternatively you could have two arrays in your plist. One is the list of entries and the other is a matching list of bools.

Comment: but then how to display checkmark on the rows whose values are present in the plist

Comment: @Rani it is very simple set cell.accessoryType = checkmarkaccessoary when displaying data from plist in cellforrow at index path method

Answer (score 1):

You can have a structure like this each value of plist should contain a dictionary. Like in you example entertainment will be a dictionary by default you can add a bool flag to the dictionary. Something like this

```
NSDictionary *entertainmentDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Entertainment",@"name",[NSNUmber numberWithBool:YES],@"Checked",nil];
```

Then when displaying in table you can get the value of bool flag from dictionary
like this

```
NSDictionary *entD = [arrayOfPlistItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
BOOL checked = [[entD objectForKey:@"Checked"] boolValue];
//Not replace this with actual code it is for explaining purpose only
if(checked) {
    cell.accessoryType = checkmarktype;

}else {
  cell.accessoryType = none;
}
```

Hope you will understand from this

Comment: rahul i am totally getting confused bcoz i have created array in plist so what should i create in plist

Comment: @Rani create NSDictionary for each item.

Comment: @Rani if you are getting struck send me code I'll update the code and send back to you.